# Script works until it's modified to redirect stdout & stderr to a log file

Tags: bash, file-descriptor

### Explanation

When <kbd>The Script</kbd> below is ran with no modifications, it outputs (correctly):

> two one START

After uncommenting the `exec` statements in the script below, file descriptor 3 points to standard output, and file descriptor 4 points to standard error:

```sh
exec 3>&1 4>&2
```

And all standard output & standard error gets logged to a file instead of printing to the console:

```sh
# Two variances seen in the script below
exec 1>"TEST-${mode:1}.log" 2>&1  # Log Name based on subcommand
exec 1>"TEST-bootstrap.log" 2>&1  # Initial "bootstrap" log file
```

When the exec statements are in place, the script should create three files (with contents):

`TEST-bootstrap.log` (sucessfully created - empty file)

> 

`TEST-one.log` (sucessfully created)

> one START

`TEST-two.log` (is not created)

> two one START

But instead it seems to stop after the first log file and never creates `TEST-two.log`. What could be the issue considering it works with the `exec` statements commented out?

### The Script

```sh
#!/bin/bash
SELFD=$(cd -P $(dirname ${0}) >/dev/null 2>&1; pwd)  # Current scripts directory
SELF=$(basename ${0})   # Current scripts name
SELFX=${SELFD}/${SELF}  # The current script exec path

fnOne() { echo "one ${*}"; }
fnTwo() { echo "two ${*}"; }

subcommand() {
    # exec 3>&1 4>&2
    # exec 1>"TEST-${mode:1}.log" 2>&1
    case "${mode}" in
        -one) fnOne   ${*}; ;;
        -two) fnTwo   ${*}; ;;
    esac
}

bootstrap() {
    # exec 3>&1 4>&2
    # exec 1>"TEST-bootstrap.log" 2>&1
    echo "START" \
        | while read line; do ${SELFX} -one ${line}; done \
        | while read line; do ${SELFX} -two ${line}; done
    exit 0
}

mode=${1}; shift

case "${mode:0:1}" in
    -) subcommand ${*} ;;
    *) bootstrap ${mode} ${*} ;;
esac
exit 0
```

This script is strictly an isolated example of the problem I am facing in another more complex script of mine. I've tried to keep it as concise as possible but will expand upon it if needed.

### What I'm trying to accomplish (extra reading for those interested)

In <kbd>The Script</kbd> above, I am using while loops instead of [gnu-parallel](/questions/tagged/gnu-parallel) for simplicity sake, and am using simple functions that echo "one" and "two" for ease of debugging & asking the question here.

In my actual script, the program would have the following functions: `list-archives`, `download`, `extract`, `process` that would fetch a list of archives from a URL, download them, extract their contents, and process the resulting files respectively. Considering these operations take a varying amount of time, I planned on running them in parallel. My script's `bootstrap()` function would look something like this:

```sh
# program ./myscript
list-archives "${1}" \
    | parallel myscript -download \
    | parallel myscript -extract \
    | parallel myscript -process
```

And would be called like this:

```
./myscript "http://www.example.com"
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is a way to start a program that can can call it's own functions in parallel and record everything it does. This would be useful to determine when the data was last fetched, debug any errors, etc.

I'd also like to have the program record logs when it's invoked with a subcommand, e.g.

```sh
# only list achives
>> ./myscript -list-archives "http://www.example.com"
# download this specific archive
>> ./myscript -download "http://www.example.com/archive.zip" 
# ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the problem:

```
echo "START" \
    | while read line; do ${SELFX} -one ${line}; done \
    | while read line; do ${SELFX} -two ${line}; done
```

The first `while` loop reads `START` from the `echo` statement. The second `while` loop processes the output of the first `while` loop. But since the script is redirecting stdout to a file, nothing is piped to the second loop, so it exits immediately.

I'm not sure how to "fix" this, since it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. If you want to feed something to the next command in the pipeline, you can echo to FD 3, which you've carefully used to save the original stdout.

Comment: I read the whole program and ran all its variants and I agree. It's easy enough to understand what happens, but hard to figure out what was intended. Maybe the output of the `-one` instance was supposed to go both places (the log file and into the pipe) in which case a `tee /dev/fd/3` could do it.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley It never came to mind to use /dev/fd directly - I'll mess around in that area a bit. I've added in more context into my question towards the end. I'm going to work at it keeping these suggestions in mind as I gather a solution. Will post back later, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've accepted [@Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17755006/586621) as the answer and the comment left by [@Wumpus Q. Wumbley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2404501/wumpus-q-wumbley) nudged me in the right direction.

The solution was to use `tee /dev/fd/3` on the case statement like so:

```sh
subcommand() {
    exec 3>&1 4>&2
    exec 1>"TEST-${mode:1}.log" 2>&1
    case "${mode}" in
        -one) fnOne   ${*}; ;;
        -two) fnTwo   ${*}; ;;
    esac | tee /dev/fd/3
}
```